# Undefined symbols: __dyld_func_lookup for MacOSX 64-bit linking error in 10.6.7

Tags: undefined, symbols, dyld

I'm trying to compile a program that references `__dyld_func_lookup`.

Everything compiles fine, indicating include files were able to find the function reference. However, upon the final linking, I get this error:

```
g++ -o ../lib/macosx64/libcogmapapi.dylib -dynamiclib  ./build/CogMapApi.o ./libs/cmlabs/macosx64/AIR.a ./libs/cmlabs/macosx64/CoreLibrary.a  
Undefined symbols:
  "__dyld_func_lookup", referenced from:
      _reference in CoreLibrary.a(dlfcn_darwin.o)
      _dllopen in CoreLibrary.a(dlfcn_darwin.o)
      _dllopen in CoreLibrary.a(dlfcn_darwin.o)
      _dllopen in CoreLibrary.a(dlfcn_darwin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried using `-undefined dynamic_lookup` in the linker and it does link properly, but then at runtime I get the undefined symbol as I do actually reference `__dyld_func_lookup` in my code. I'm guessing I need to link to some dylib or framework, but everything I tried like System and libdl.dylib did not seem to work.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Linking dylib1.0 worked for me in same situation.

Comment: Could elaborate on this one please, for people who are coming here from google? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: there's no context provided with your asnwer.  Are you setting the linking within Xcode? Or you passing the a flag directly to GCC / LLVM from the command line?

Comment: @Chris I linked it in Xcode UI as far as I remember. But I don't see why passing it to gcc as parameter wouldn't work. I can't tell now which version of Xcode/gcc I was using back then, sorry. 6 years ago it could be Xcode 3 or 4

Comment: no worries dude, your answer just came across as super ambiguous / vague to say the least, but that's just my opinion.